# Unhandled exception in xamarin forms app after setting SetContentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to place my app icon on the left side of the toolbar, so I placed an `ImageButton` in Toolbar.axml. I set the `SetContentView` so that I can access the `ImageButton` using `FindViewById` and Listen to the click event.

But After adding the `SetContentView` line my app throws UnhandledException.

Below is my Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
       android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

   <ImageButton
       android:src="@drawable/appicon"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:id="@+id/homeicon" />
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my MainActivity.cs is like below:

```
[Activity(Label = "XamarinToolBar", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = 
"@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = 
ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : 
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            //ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            ImageButton homeButton = (ImageButton)FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.homeicon);
            homeButton.Click += HomeButton_Click;

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        private void HomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is here :

> public class MainActivity : 
>           global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity

You are mixing up the xamarin forms FormsAppCompatActivity with your AppCompactActivity and remove these two lines from your cs file

```
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
```

I hope it helps

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

i think you are trying to mix and match the xamarin.forms "FormsAppCompatActivity" and make it behave like a normal android Activity in which shouldn't be the case because xamarin.forms "FormsAppCompatActivity" has its own underlying rendering engine through the use of xaml pages (e.g. ContentPage, MasterDetailPage etc.). Try to create an Android project instead.